# Move particles using tsparticles along svg paths in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, svg, particles.js

I am trying to move the particles along svg path for my component and so far I have no luck. I cannot find any useful information on particlejs docs. here is my component :

```
const options3 = useMemo(()=>{
        return {
          "autoPlay": true,
          "background": {
            "color": {
              "value": "#000"
            },
            "image": "",
            "position": "",
            "repeat": "",
            "size": "",
            "opacity": 1
          },
          "backgroundMask": {
            "composite": "destination-out",
            "cover": {
              "color": {
                "value": "#fff"
              },
              "opacity": 1
            },
            "enable": false
          },
          "defaultThemes": {},
          "delay": 0,
          "fullScreen": {
            "enable": true,
            "zIndex": -1
          },
          "detectRetina": true,
          "duration": 0,
          "fpsLimit": 120,
          "interactivity": {
            "detectsOn": "window",
            "events": {
              "onClick": {
                "enable": false,
                "mode": []
              },
              "onDiv": {
                "selectors": [],
                "enable": false,
                "mode": [],
                "type": "circle"
              },
              "onHover": {
                "enable": false,
                "mode": [],
                "parallax": {
                  "enable": false,
                  "force": 2,
                  "smooth": 10
                }
              },
              "resize": {
                "delay": 0.5,
                "enable": true
              }
            },
            "modes": {
              "attract": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4,
                "easing": "ease-out-quad",
                "factor": 1,
                "maxSpeed": 50,
                "speed": 1
              },
              "bounce": {
                "distance": 200
              },
              "bubble": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4,
                "mix": false,
                "divs": {
                  "distance": 200,
                  "duration": 0.4,
                  "mix": false,
                  "selectors": []
                }
              },
              "connect": {
                "distance": 80,
                "links": {
                  "opacity": 0.5
                },
                "radius": 60
              },
              "grab": {
                "distance": 100,
                "links": {
                  "blink": false,
                  "consent": false,
                  "opacity": 1
                }
              },
              "push": {
                "default": true,
                "groups": [],
                "quantity": 4
              },
              "remove": {
                "quantity": 2
              },
              "repulse": {
                "distance": 200,
                "duration": 0.4,
                "factor": 100,
                "speed": 1,
                "maxSpeed": 50,
                "easing": "ease-out-quad",
                "divs": {
                  "distance": 200,
                  "duration": 0.4,
                  "factor": 100,
                  "speed": 1,
                  "maxSpeed": 50,
                  "easing": "ease-out-quad",
                  "selectors": []
                }
              },
              "slow": {
                "factor": 3,
                "radius": 200
              },
              "trail": {
                "delay": 1,
                "pauseOnStop": false,
                "quantity": 1
              },
              "light": {
                "area": {
                  "gradient": {
                    "start": {
                      "value": "#ffffff"
                    },
                    "stop": {
                      "value": "#000000"
                    }
                  },
                  "radius": 1000
                },
                "shadow": {
                  "color": {
                    "value": "#000000"
                  },
                  "length": 2000
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "manualParticles": [],
          "particles": {
            "bounce": {
              "horizontal": {
                "random": {
                  "enable": false,
                  "minimumValue": 0.1
                },
                "value": 1
              },
              "vertical": {
                "random": {
                  "enable": false,
                  "minimumValue": 0.1
                },
                "value": 1
              }
            },
            "collisions": {
              "absorb": {
                "speed": 2
              },
              "bounce": {
                "horizontal": {
                  "random": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "minimumValue": 0.1
                  },
                  "value": 1
                },
                "vertical": {
                  "random": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "minimumValue": 0.1
                  },
                  "value": 1
                }
              },
              "enable": false,
              "mode": "bounce",
              "overlap": {
                "enable": true,
                "retries": 0
              }
            },
            "color": {
              "value": "#FF0000",
              "animation": {
                "h": {
                  "count": 0,
                  "enable": true,
                  "offset": 0,
                  "speed": 10,
                  "decay": 0,
                  "sync": true
                },
                "s": {
                  "count": 0,
                  "enable": false,
                  "offset": 0,
                  "speed": 1,
                  "decay": 0,
                  "sync": true
                },
                "l": {
                  "count": 0,
                  "enable": false,
                  "offset": 0,
                  "speed": 1,
                  "decay": 0,
                  "sync": true
                }
              }
            },
            "groups": {},
            "move": {
              "angle": {
                "offset": 0,
                "value": 90
              },
              "attract": {
                "distance": 200,
                "enable": true,
                "rotate": {
                  "x": 2000,
                  "y": 2000
                }
              },
              "center": {
                "x": 50,
                "y": 50,
                "mode": "percent",
                "radius": 0
              },
              "decay": 0,
              "distance": {},
              "direction": "none",
              "drift": 0,
              "enable": true,
              "gravity": {
                "acceleration": 9.81,
                "enable": false,
                "inverse": false,
                "maxSpeed": 50
              },
              "path": {
                "clamp": false,
                "delay": {
                  "random": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "minimumValue": 0
                  },
                  "value": 0
                },
                "enable": true,
                "options": {
                  "sides": 6,
                  "turnSteps": 30,
                  "angle": 30,
                  "svg": {
                    "path": "M10 10 L90 90",
                    "stroke": "#ffffff",
                    "strokeWidth": 2,
                    "scale": 1,
                    "rotation": 0,
                  },
                },

              },
              "outModes": {
                "default": "destroy",
                "bottom": "destroy",
                "left": "destroy",
                "right": "destroy",
                "top": "destroy"
              },
              "random": false,
              "size": false,
              "speed": 3,
              "spin": {
                "acceleration": 0,
                "enable": false
              },
              "straight": false,
              "trail": {
                "enable": true,
                "length": 20,
                "fill": {
                  "color": {
                    "value": "#000"
                  }
                }
              },
              "vibrate": false,
              "warp": false
            },
            "number": {
              "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1080
              },
              "limit": 0,
              "value": 0
            },
            "opacity": {
              "random": {
                "enable": false,
                "minimumValue": 0.1
              },
              "value": 1,
              "animation": {
                "count": 0,
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 2,
                "decay": 0,
                "sync": false,
                "destroy": "none",
                "startValue": "random"
              }
            },
            "reduceDuplicates": false,
            "shadow": {
              "blur": 0,
              "color": {
                "value": "#000"
              },
              "enable": false,
              "offset": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0
              }
            },
            "shape": {
              "options": {},
              "type": "circle"
            },
            "size": {
              "random": {
                "enable": false,
                "minimumValue": 1
              },
              "value": 2,
              "animation": {
                "count": 0,
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 5,
                "decay": 0,
                "sync": false,
                "destroy": "none",
                "startValue": "random"
              }
            },
            "stroke": {
              "width": 0
            },
            "zIndex": {
              "random": {
                "enable": false,
                "minimumValue": 0
              },
              "value": 0,
              "opacityRate": 1,
              "sizeRate": 1,
              "velocityRate": 1
            },
            "life": {
              "count": 0,
              "delay": {
                "random": {
                  "enable": false,
                  "minimumValue": 0
                },
                "value": 0,
                "sync": false
              },
              "duration": {
                "random": {
                  "enable": false,
                  "minimumValue": 0.0001
                },
                "value": 0,
                "sync": false
              }
            },
            "rotate": {
              "random": {
                "enable": false,
                "minimumValue": 0
              },
              "value": 0,
              "animation": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 0,
                "decay": 0,
                "sync": false
              },
              "direction": "clockwise",
              "path": false
            },
            "destroy": {
              "bounds": {},
              "mode": "none",
              "split": {
                "count": 1,
                "factor": {
                  "random": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "minimumValue": 0
                  },
                  "value": 3
                },
                "rate": {
                  "random": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "minimumValue": 0
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "min": 4,
                    "max": 9
                  }
                },
                "sizeOffset": true,
                "particles": {}
              }
            },
            "roll": {
              "darken": {
                "enable": false,
                "value": 0
              },
              "enable": false,
              "enlighten": {
                "enable": false,
                "value": 0
              },
              "mode": "vertical",
              "speed": 25
            },
            "tilt": {
              "random": {
                "enable": false,
                "minimumValue": 0
              },
              "value": 0,
              "animation": {
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 0,
                "decay": 0,
                "sync": false
              },
              "direction": "clockwise",
              "enable": false
            },
            "twinkle": {
              "lines": {
                "enable": false,
                "frequency": 0.05,
                "opacity": 1
              },
              "particles": {
                "enable": false,
                "frequency": 0.05,
                "opacity": 1
              }
            },
            "wobble": {
              "distance": 5,
              "enable": false,
              "speed": {
                "angle": 50,
                "move": 10
              }
            },
            "orbit": {
              "animation": {
                "count": 0,
                "enable": false,
                "speed": 1,
                "decay": 0,
                "sync": false
              },
              "enable": false,
              "opacity": 1,
              "rotation": {
                "random": {
                  "enable": false,
                  "minimumValue": 0
                },
                "value": 45
              },
              "width": 1
            },
            "links": {
              "blink": false,
              "color": {
                "value": "#fff"
              },
              "consent": false,
              "distance": 100,
              "enable": false,
              "frequency": 1,
              "opacity": 1,
              "shadow": {
                "blur": 5,
                "color": {
                  "value": "#000"
                },
                "enable": false
              },
              "triangles": {
                "enable": false,
                "frequency": 1
              },
              "width": 1,
              "warp": false
            },
            "repulse": {
              "random": {
                "enable": false,
                "minimumValue": 0
              },
              "value": 0,
              "enabled": false,
              "distance": 1,
              "duration": 1,
              "factor": 1,
              "speed": 1
            }
          },
          "pauseOnBlur": true,
          "pauseOnOutsideViewport": true,
          "responsive": [],
          "smooth": false,
          "style": {},
          "themes": [],
          "zLayers": 100,
          "emitters": {
            "autoPlay": true,
            "fill": true,
            "life": {
              "wait": false
            },
            "rate": {
              "quantity": 1,
              "delay": 0.25
            },
            "shape": "square",
            "startCount": 0,
            "size": {
              "mode": "percent",
              "height": 0,
              "width": 0
            },
            "direction": "none",
            "particles": {},
            "position": {
              "x": 50,
              "y": 50
            }
          },

        };
      });

  const particlesInit = useCallback(async engine => {
    // you can initiate the tsParticles instance (engine) here, adding custom shapes or presets
    // this loads the tsparticles package bundle, it's the easiest method for getting everything ready
    // starting from v2 you can add only the features you need reducing the bundle size
    await loadFull(engine);
    await loadPolygonMaskPlugin(engine);
}, []);

const particlesLoaded = useCallback(async container => {
    await console.log(container);
}, []);

    // return <Particles init={particlesInit} options={options} />
    return <Particles
    id="tsparticles"
    init={particlesInit}
    loaded={particlesLoaded}
    options={options3}
/>;
};

export default ParticlesComponent;
```

I've exported the config from 'Hexagons' Sample on https://particles.js.org/ main page which is moving particles along hexagons using a generator which I have no idea how it works too. I've replaced the generator with :

```
"path": {
                "clamp": false,
                "delay": {
                  "random": {
                    "enable": false,
                    "minimumValue": 0
                  },
                  "value": 0
                },
                "enable": true,
                "options": {
                  "sides": 6,
                  "turnSteps": 30,
                  "angle": 30,
                  "svg": {
                    "path": "M10 10 L90 90",
                    "stroke": "#ffffff",
                    "strokeWidth": 2,
                    "scale": 1,
                    "rotation": 0,
                  },
                },
```

Does anyone have any idea about how can I manage to do that?